# Relating $f(x)$ to its Laplace Transform for values other than $x=0$?

Tags: pr.probability, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, laplace-transform, tauberian-theorems

Suppose $X\in (0,1]$ is a random variable where $f(x)$ is its CDF and $g(t)$ is the Laplace Transform of $f(x)$. Tauberian theorems (Theorem 2.3 in Coqueret's "Approximation of probabilistic Laplace Transforms and their inverses" [paper](https://web.archive.org/web/20180722184403id_/https://msp.org/camcos/2012/7-2/camcos-v7-n2-s.pdf#page=100)) relate behavior of $f(x)$ for $x\to 0$ to behavior of $g(t)$ for $t\to \infty$.

Can we relate the two functions for other values of $x$ and $t$?

As an example, take random variable whose CDF switches from $O(x)$ to $O(x^2)$ behavior around $x=0.01$. Its Laplace transform switches from $O(t^{-2})$ to $O(t^{-1})$ around $t=200$. Can this be generalized?

[image]

[Notebook](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/nn-linear/forum-mgf-from-cdf.nb)

More precisely, given $g(t)$, piecewise linear on log-log scale, specified using a list of cut-off and slope/intercept pairs, can we obtain $X\in (0,1]$ with CDF $f(x)$ such that $\mathcal{L}(f)=g$?

Motivation: gradient descent of neural network training objectives [appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6TJY.png) piecewise linear on log-log plot (Figure 1 of "broken neural scaling laws" [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2210.14891.pdf)). I'd like to use this to make a testable hypothesis on the shape of the spectral density.

Comment: Your question seems unclear and too open to me. In particular, what do you mean by "other values of $x$"? Values of $x$ should be considered in conjunction with the corresponding values of $t$. In your example, the "switching" value $0.01$ of $x$ is **still small**, with the corresponding "switching" value $200\asymp\frac1{100}$ of $t$.

Comment: @IosifPinelis right, $x/t$ are connected. I was looking for theorems that would allow me to relate power law behavior of $g(t)$ to power law behavior of $f(x)$, in a more general way than classical Tauberian (which predicts $O(x)$ regime but not $O(x^2)$ regime in the toy example)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I think I understand your question better now, but still not quite. Do you want the exponent $p(x)$ in $f(x)=x^{p(x)}$ to vary smoothly or piecewise, and how fast?

Comment: So are you asking whether one can compute the inverse Laplace transform of some $e^{g(x)}$ where $g(x)$ is a piecewise continuous? The more details you can add on $g$ the easier it will be to check eg. integrability, tail behaviour , derivatives-existence.

Comment: @ThomasKojar yes, except its log-log scale, so $e^{g(\log x)}$

Comment: Generally Tauberian theorems only give asymptotic behaviours.

Comment: I see. Can you add any more list of properties you have for $g(x)$ in your post? The more specific the better. (Since you have an application in mind, I imagine you might know some things about g).

Comment: @ThomasKojar $g(t)$ is empirically obtained by looking at neural network training loss over time and observing that piecewise linear is a good fit (you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fut0r.png)). I'm trying to obtain obtain shape of the CDF of the spectrum and test it empirically

Comment: @IosifPinelis I'm starting with $g(t)$ which is piecewise linear in log-log scale, with 5 segments like [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YtepL.png), and trying to describe a random variable $X\in (0,1]$ such that its CDF $f(x)$  produces $g(t)$ after Laplace Transform

Comment: What is the global behaviour of $g(y)$ for all $y=logx$? Does it diverge as $y\to -\infty$ but hits zero for some $y_{0}>0$ and then it is identically zero? If does diverge, how fast i.e. is it just  diverging like $g(y)\sim-y$ as $y\to -\infty$ ? I am asking because we need to know exact tail behaviours in order to integrate the Bromwich contour.

Comment: @ThomasKojar $g(0)$ is a constant number and $g(\infty)=0$ . For negative numbers value of $g$ is impossible to measure, so it's unspecified here

Comment: how fast does it decay to zero? Is it $1/t$? Is existence of $f(x)$ enough for you? What if we just get a continuous variable $X$ but without any density i.e. singular measure? Here we can use distribution theory to get it even if you have singular tails.

Comment: If $f$ is increasing, then $f(s) \ge f(x) \mathbb 1_{[x,\infty)}(s)$, and so $g(1/x) \ge e^{-1} f(x)$. If $f(x)/x$ is decreasing, then $f(s) \le (s/x) f(x) \mathbb 1_{(0, x]}(s)$, and therefore $g(1/x) \ge (1 - \tfrac{2}{e}) f(x)$. And of course there are many more similar inequalities, which give bounds rather than asymptotic equalities. You may like the chapter on $O$-regularly varying functions in the Bingham–Goldie–Teugels book.